# Update a subdocument list object value in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, rethinkdb-python

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "subdocuments": [
        {
            "id": "A",
            "name": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "B",
            "name": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "C",
            "name": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

How do update a subdocument "A"s "name" to a value of 2 in RethinkDB in either Javascript or Python?

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely of the position of your "A " element you can update like this:

```
r.db("DB").table("TABLE").get(1)
  .update({subdocuments:
    r.row("subdocuments").changeAt(0, r.row("subdocuments").nth(0).merge({"name":2}))})
```

If you can not rely on the position, you have to find it yourself:

```
r.db("DB").table("TABLE").get(1).do(function(doc){
  return doc("subdocuments").offsetsOf(function(sub){return sub("id").match("A")}).nth(0)
    .do(function(index){ 
      return r.db("DB").table("TABLE").update({"subdocuments": 
        doc("subdocuments").changeAt(index, doc("subdocuments").nth(index).merge({"name":2})) })})
})
```

As an alternative you can use the map function to iterate over the array elements and update the one that matches your condition

```
r.db("DB").table("TABLE").get(1)
   .update({
     subdocuments: r.row("subdocuments").map(function(sub){  
       return r.branch(sub("id").eq("A"), sub.merge({name: 2}), sub)
     })
   })
```

Comment: This seems kind of complicated to do a simple operation. Is this really the easiest way?

Comment: You can modify your data model, e.g.:
{"id":1,"subdocuments":{"A":{"name":1},"B":{"name":2},"C":{"name":3}}} then you will be able to do the update like this:
...get(1).update({"subdocuments":{"A":{"name":2}}})